# To Show Value using Condition inside <td> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

```
<td id="TemplateNameLabel">    
    <span ng-if="{{oprMode}} === 'IN'">*Template Name</span>
    <span ng-if="{{oprMode}} === 'UP'">*Edit Template Name</span>     
</td>
```

Where `oprMode` is JavaScript variable.

```
<script>
    var oprMode = 'IN';
</script>
```

Comment: use `ng-if="oprMode"` and not `ng-if="{{oprMode}}"`

Comment: I tried this also. But showing both value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use use `ng-if="oprMode" === 'IN'` and not `ng-if="{{oprMode}} === 'IN'"`

`ng-if` is already a angular directive. and `oprMode` should be a variable in the corresponding controller scope, or in upwards ^^^ scopes (assuming you are not using `controller as` with your syntax)

**EDIT**

Assuming you don't have any idea on angularjs, with simple javascript:

```
<td id="TemplateNameLabel">    
    <span ng-if="{{oprMode}} === 'IN'">*Template Name</span>
    <span ng-if="{{oprMode}} === 'UP'">*Edit Template Name</span>     
</td>
```

and in script

```
var oprMode = 'IN'
document.querySelector('#TemplateNameLabel > span').innerText = oprMode === 'IN' ? '*Template Name' : oprMode === 'UP' ? '*Edit Template Name' : '';
```

Comment: create a angular controller and put the variable inside the scope of that controller.

Comment: am not using angular js in my application. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: to do with simple javascript

Comment: `ng-if` is a angular's thing right,you I suggest you start learing basic of javascript first and then angular if you like it. for now edited the answer for your reference of plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

use only **ng-if="oprMode"** here you are using ng-if="{{oprMode}}".

```
<td id="TemplateNameLabel">    
    <span ng-if="oprMode === 'IN'">*Template Name</span>
    <span ng-if="oprMode === 'UP'">*Edit Template Name</span>     
</td>
```

Comment: she is trying with a simple javascript variable inside `window`, and not in controller.

Comment: I think she dosent have Angular js